# Python, MonkeyRunner. How to find a package name inside all list packages?

Tags: android, python, testing, android-virtual-device, monkeyrunner

everybody.
I´m using python and monkeyrunner for test apps on AVDs, I´m writing an script that could test if an app is installed or not.

I have a package name like:

```
package_name = "package:me.abc.app"
```

And I have a list of packages installed on an AVD with this command:

```
C:\test>adb shell pm list packages
package:com.example.android.notepad
package:com.android.smoketest
package:com.example.android.softkeyb
package:me.abc.app
package:com.android.smoketest.tests
```

I want to write a script where I could save that list in an array/list and do something like this:

```
If package_name is in list_of_packages
   print "App is installed"
else
   print "App is not installed"
```

I´m having problemn with how could I save that list in an array or list, in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created this function to save the list packages and you can search in that.

```
def search_package_in_avd(device):
    command = device.shell("pm list packages -3")
    splitedline=re.split(':|\r|\n',command)
    if not splitedline:
        return ""
    else:
        return splitedline
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import subprocess

apps_proc = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "shell", "pm", "list", "packages"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
list_of_packages = apps_proc.communicate()[0].decode.strip()
```

I have not tried it but you can play with the last line to get what you need.